# Model Search in Yii not returning full results of the table

Tags: php, yii

I am using model search functionality of Yii framework for search,but it is not returning complete results when I use it without any filters.
Can anyone help???

$model->search()->getData(); is the command I am using to fetch the results.

Here is my sample code:-

```
$model=new modelName('search');
$results = $model->search()->getData();
```

in Model just normal search criteria

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$model->search() returns a CActiveDataProvider object. By default, CActiveDataProvider queries are paginated. This is useful, because CActiveRecords are memory intensive and in web applications a pagination result is generally expected.

You should loop trough the CActiveDataProvider pages or disable pagination on CActiveDataProvider.

**Solution 1: use CDataProviderIterator to loop trough all CActiveDataProvider  pages**

This is often the best option, cause CDataProviderIterator iterates over all results in CActiveDataProvider keeping low memory usage.

```
$results = $model->search();
$iterator = new CDataProviderIterator($results );
foreach($iterator as $model) {
   ...
}
```

**Solution 2: disable pagination (not recommended)**

```
$results = $model->search();
$results->setPagination(false);
foreach($results->getData() as $model) {
    ...
}
```